# Perl regex match has multiple empty lines

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse through a string with perl and put the matches into an array.

Ex. "FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1, VALUE2, FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3, VALUE4, FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5"

Output:

```
FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1
VALUE2
FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3
VALUE4
FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5
```

My code:

```
my $in = "FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1, VALUE2, FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3, VALUE4, FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5";

my @cols = ($in =~ /((?&full_m)),?
(?(DEFINE)
            (?<full_m>(?&full_f)|(?&word))
            (?<full_f>(?&func)\s(?&word))
            (?<func>(?&word)\((?&worf)\))
            (?<worf>(?&func)|(?&word))
            (?<word>\s*\w+\s*)
        )/gx);
print "$in\n";

my $count = 1;
foreach (@cols) {
    print "$count: $_\n";
    ++$count;
}
```

The problem is that I get the matches but also 5 empty matches after.

```
1: FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 
7:  VALUE2
8: 
9: 
10: 
11: 
12: 
13:  FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3
14: 
15: 
16: 
17: 
18: 
19:  VALUE4
20: 
21: 
22: 
23: 
24: 
25:  FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5
26: 
27: 
28: 
29: 
30:
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a `worf` instead of a `word` in there?

Comment: the result in `@cols` contains the whole match but also the content of each group you have defined in your pattern. That's why you obtain 5 empty items.

Comment: Why does it also have the groups? I thought that it would only show what's inside the parentheses?

Comment: Groups in the `(?(DEFINE)...)` are also inside parentheses.

Comment: What's wrong with `split /,/`?

Comment: that would work, but I planned on adding match for something like FUNC1(VALUE1, VALUE2) VALUE1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the same thing except it just store group 1 into the col's array.

```
my $in = "FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1, VALUE2, FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3, VALUE4, FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5";
my @cols;
while ($in =~ /((?&full_m)),?(?(DEFINE)(?<full_m>(?&full_f)|(?&word))(?<full_f>(?&func)\s(?&word))(?<func>(?&word)\((?&worf)\))(?<worf>(?&func)|(?&word))(?<word>\s*\w+\s*))/gx)
{
   push @cols, $1;
}
print "$in\n";

my $count = 1;
foreach (@cols) {
    print "$count: $_\n";
    ++$count;
}
```

Output

```
FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1, VALUE2, FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3, VALUE4, FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5
1: FUNC1(VALUE1) VALUE1
2:  VALUE2
3:  FUNC2(FUNC1(VALUE3)) VALUE3
4:  VALUE4
5:  FUNC3(VALUE5) VALUE5
```

To better see the regex, formatting is needed

```
 ( (?&full_m) )                # (1)
 ,?
 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<full_m>                    # (2 start)
           (?&full_f) 
        |  (?&word)
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?<full_f>                    # (3 start)
           (?&func) \s (?&word)
      )                             # (3 end)
      (?<func>                      # (4 start)
           (?&word) \( (?&worf) \)
      )                             # (4 end)
      (?<worf>                      # (5 start)
           (?&func) 
        |  (?&word)
      )                             # (5 end)
      (?<word> \s* \w+ \s* )        # (6)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I'm still not sure why my version had the matched groups added.

Comment: Look at the formatted regex, the other groups are recorded when you do `@ary = $s ~= //g;`. However, when you call the groups as functions, from (?(DEFINE)), their group values are overwritten but its match is returned to the caller.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick explanation!